# SQL select query join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, select-query

Below are my MYSQL tables. I am not able to figure out what a MySQl query looks like that selects only one row from parent for each month (by latest date in a month) and its consequent child rows. So in the given example it should return rows from the child table with IDs 4,5,6,10,11,12

[image]

Comment: Could you include what you have tried so far? What is the database you are using - MySQL, SQL Server?

Comment: @zedfoxus I am using mysql, updated the description.

Comment: Kaizar I cant understand your logic on why `IDs 4,5,6,10,11,12` are the one selected.

Comment: I also did not understand the logic.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Because IDs 4,5,6 and 10,11,12 belongs to parent ID 2 and 4 respectively which has the latest date for that month.

Comment: So any of the answer solve your problem or still need help?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza haven't tested yet but looking at the answers looks any of them will do the job, Personally I would prefer the shortest sql which I think Moon has answered though JNevill's query is more robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like the following would do the trick for you:

```
SELECT Child.id 
FROM parent 
    INNER JOIN Child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
WHERE parent.`date` IN (SELECT max(`date`) FROM parent GROUP BY YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`))
```

The fun part is the `WHERE` clause where we only grab `parent` table records where the `date` is the `max(date)` for that particular month/year combination.

Comment: How do you know which month belongs to which id?

Comment: Why would I care? Just need the max date for each month.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's split this in parts:

First, select the max date from the `parent` table, grouping by month:

```
select max(`date`) as max_date from parent group by last_day(`date`)
-- The "last_day()" function returns the last day of the month for a given date
```

Then, select the corresponding row from the parent table:

```
select parent.*
from parent
     inner join (select max(`date`) as max_date from parent group by last_day(`date`)) as a
             on parent.`date` = a.max_date
```

Finally, select the corresponding rows in the `child` table:

```
select child.*
from child
     inner join parent
             on child.parent_id = parent.id
     inner join (select max(`date`) as max_date from parent group by last_day(`date`)) as a
             on parent.`date` = a.max_date;
```

You can check how this works on this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00e2d/1).

---

**EDIT**

The above solution works, but if your tables are big, you may face a problem because the joined data is not indexed. One way to solve this is to create a temporary table and use this temp table to get your final result:

```
drop table if exists temp_max_date;
create temporary table temp_max_date
    select max(`date`) as max_date 
    from parent 
    group by last_day(`date`);
alter table temp_max_date
    add index idx_max_date(max_date);
-- Get the final data:
select child.*
from child
     inner join parent
             on child.parent_id = parent.id
     inner join temp_max_date as a
             on parent.`date` = a.max_date;
```

[Here's the SQL fiddle for this second solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45f15/1).

Temporary tables are only accesible to the connection that creates them, and are destroyed when the connection is closed or killed.

**Remember:** Add the appropriate indexes to your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Child WHERE PARENT_ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Parent GROUP BY LAST_DAY(DATE)
)
```

Here is the working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8880/8

Comment: This assume `ID` Increase according to `DATE`. That isnt always true

Answer (score 0):

This solution is clunky in its inability to properly employ indexes, but it's easier to write than one that would...

```
SELECT a.*
     , c.id 
  FROM parent a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m')yearmonth
            , MAX(date) max_date 
         FROM parent 
        GROUP 
           BY yearmonth
     ) b 
    ON b.max_date = a.date 
  JOIN child c 
    ON c.parent_id = a.id;
```